# Include manually (not through VS) a file into csproj without being overridden

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csproj

I am trying to develop a project that generates code. One of the code files it generates is sql code and I am trying to include it in one of the projects of my solution.
Since I didn't find yet a solution to do this programmatically, I tried to modify the .csproj manually:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="DIL\*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What my code does it generate a Test.Sql and places it into the DIL folder without including it in the project. If I then go modifying the .csproj as shown above and reload the .csproj itself I will find the Test.sql being added.

However there will be no **Build Include="DIL*.sql" /** anymore in the .csproj, meaning that if I generate another sql file it will not be added automatically to the project. Is there a permanent solution to this by any chance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Putting a file in the main folder where the cs file is located will not overwrite the file.  Only if it is in the bin folder will the file get removed if a clean build is made.  From VS you can add any file to a project by using Add Existing and then browse for the file.  You can then right click the file in VS and select the Copy Property where the file will get copied to the bin folder.

Comment: @jdweng sorry there but I dont get it at all :/ how is this even inherent at all to my question? Big time apologies in case I didn't get what you meant!

Comment: @jdweng I am asking for a way to tell the .csproj xml to include any file through a wildcard. It works, and as soon as I modify manually the xml it will include the files. However after reloading the project the wildcard disappear and any new generated file will not be added automatically anymore to the proj.

Comment: How do you reload?  I don't reload so I'm not sure the process you are using.

Comment: @jdweng on VS there is the unload and reload option for a project. You need to unload it to modify the .csproj xml and reload it to apply the changes. When I reload it the wildcard applies and includes my generated files, so it works. But the wildcard disappears from the xml and therefore won't include anymore any further new generated file

Comment: May be it would be better to use the c# command line compiler instead of using the VS compiler.  The command line compiler has more options than in VS.